# Tensorflow While Body Not Executing

Tags: while-loop, tensorflow

I have a FIFO Queue reading from tfrecords file in tensorflow. Each record is consisted of an image and its annotation, that is, a set of features. I was trying to skip some images that is, not feeding them into the graph, or not viewing them, according to some features in mind. Therefore, I thought that the best case scenario was to use on a while loop. That loop is going to test the value of the specified feature and decide whether to proceed or not.

Kindly look at the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

num_epoch = 100

tfrecords_filename_seq = ["C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/AffectiveComputing/P16_db.tfrecords"]
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tfrecords_filename_seq, num_epochs=num_epoch, shuffle=False, name='queue')
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

current_image_confidence = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32)

def body(i):
    key, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'annotation_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

    # This is how we create one example, that is, extract one example from the database.
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    # The height and the weights are used to
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

    # The image is reshaped since when stored as a binary format, it is flattened. Therefore, we need the
    # height and the weight to restore the original image back.
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

    annotation = tf.cast(features['annotation_raw'], tf.string)
    t1 = tf.string_split([annotation], delimiter=',')
    t2 = tf.reshape(t1.values, [1, -1])
    t3 = tf.string_to_number(t2, out_type=tf.float32)
    t_ = tf.slice(t3, begin=[0, 3], size=[1, 1])

    # Note that t_ is holding a value of 1.0 or 0.0. So its a particular feature I'm interested in. 
    t_ = tf.Print(t_, data=[tf.shape(t_)], message='....')

    z = tf.cond(t_[0][0] < 1.0, lambda: tf.add(i, 0.0), lambda: tf.add(i, 1.0))

    return z

cond = lambda i: tf.equal(i, tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32))

loop = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [current_image_confidence])

init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.global_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(loop)
```

Finally, when trying to run the following code, it seems that the body is not executing and hence stuck in an infinite loop. And the `tf.Print(...)` in the body was not executed.

Why this is the case?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is getting stick because you're not starting queue runners. Run `tf.start_queue_runners()` before running your loop op.

Comment: Nop this is not the case since by adding the following line of code in the body section: `i = tf.Print(i, data=[i], message='....')` it gets executed. On the other hand, if I try the following line: `t_ = tf.Print(t_, data=[t_], message='----')` It is not executed.

Comment: t_ depends on the data dequeued but i doesn't, which is why evaluating i doesn't have to block until the queue runners start